MissingRevokeTokenAuthMethodError: Missing revocation endpoint auth method
У меня подключена Янедкс метрика к сайту. Все работало раньше нормально, но сегодня вылезла следующая ошибка -
MissingRevokeTokenAuthMethodError: Missing revocation endpoint auth method.
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/pages/get_token.py", line 28, in <module>
    oauth2 = OAuth2Component(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit_oauth/__init__.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.client = OAuth2(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/typing.py", line 687, in __call__
    result = self.__origin__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx_oauth/oauth2.py", line 197, in __init__
    raise MissingRevokeTokenAuthMethodError()

Копался в документации но ничего дельного найти не смог, подскажите где можно найти решение проблемы
Ниже мой код:
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_oauth import OAuth2Component
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import datetime as dt

# Load environment variables from .env file
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Set environment variables
AUTHORIZE_URL = os.environ.get("YM_AUTHORIZE_URL")
TOKEN_URL = os.environ.get("YM_TOKEN_URL")
REFRESH_TOKEN_URL = os.environ.get("YM_REFRESH_TOKEN_URL")
REVOKE_TOKEN_URL = os.environ.get("YM_REVOKE_TOKEN_URL")
CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("YM_CLIENT_ID")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("YM_CLIENT_SECRET")
REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get("YM_REDIRECT_URI")
SCOPE = os.environ.get("YM_SCOPE")

# Create OAuth2Component instance
oauth2 = OAuth2Component(
    # CLIENT_ID,
    # CLIENT_SECRET,
    # AUTHORIZE_URL,
    # TOKEN_URL,
    # REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
    # REVOKE_TOKEN_URL,
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorize_endpoint="https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize",
    token_endpoint="https://oauth.yandex.ru/token",
    refresh_token_endpoint="https://oauth.yandex.ru/token/refresh",
    revoke_token_endpoint="https://oauth.yandex.ru/revoke_token",
)

# Check if token exists in session state
if "token" not in st.session_state:
    # If not, show authorize button
    result = oauth2.authorize_button("Authorize", REDIRECT_URI, SCOPE)
    if result and "token" in result:
        # If authorization successful, save token in session state
        st.session_state.token = result.get("token")
        st.rerun()
else:
    # If token exists in session state, show the token
    token = st.session_state["token"]
    st.json(token)
    if st.button("Refresh Token"):
        # If refresh token button is clicked, refresh the token
        token = oauth2.refresh_token(token)
        st.session_state.token = token
        st.rerun()

if "token" in st.session_state:
    st.write(st.session_state["token"])


